# How can I add another function to listen for a click?

Tags: jquery

I am making a slide out navigation bar responsive by adding a close icon to close the menu.

On mouse-over the menu slides out and then retracts as so:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $("#brgr").hover(
    function () {
      $("#menu-full-size").addClass("is-open");
    },
    function(){
      $("#menu-full-size").hover(
        function(){
          $("#menu-full-size").addClass("is-open");  
        },
        function(){
          $("#menu-full-size").removeClass("is-open");  
        }
      );
    }
  );
});
```

Playing around with jQuery, the above syntax has kind of thrown me somewhat...

I have added a function to look out for a hover, then another hover listener to keep the slide out menu visible...but how can I add yet another to listen for a click on the close icon, and `removeClass` `.is-open`?

```
<div id="menu-full-size">
  <div class="close-nav">
    <svg viewbox="0 0 40 40">
      <path class="close-nav-x" d="M 10,10 L 30,30 M 30,10 L 10,30" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <h2>Rest of menu stuff</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('.close-nav-x').click(function(){ $("#menu-full-size").removeClass('is-open');});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use click event like below:-

```
$('.close-nav-x').click(function(){ 
   $("#menu-full-size").removeClass('is-open');
});
```

And change your code like below:-

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("#brgr").hover(function() {
        $("#menu-full-size").addClass("is-open");
    }, function() {
        $("#menu-full-size").removeClass("is-open");
    });

    $("#menu-full-size").hover(function() {
        $("#menu-full-size").addClass("is-open");
    }, function() {
        $("#menu-full-size").removeClass("is-open");
    });
    $('.close-nav-x').click(function(){ 
       $("#menu-full-size").removeClass('is-open');
    });
});
```

Once try this and let me know worked or not:-

```
$(window).load(function(){

    $("#brgr, #menu-full-size").hover(function() {
        $("#menu-full-size").addClass("is-open");
    }, function() {
        $("#menu-full-size").removeClass("is-open");
    });

    $('.close-nav-x').click(function(){ 
       $("#menu-full-size").removeClass('is-open');
    });
});
```

Comment: @davidxc  glad to help you :):)

Comment: @davidxc  i have added a third part (`Once try this and let me know worked or not:-`). You can check and let me know worked or not

Answer (score 0):

Well if i'm getting this straight this can do the job

## JQUERY

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $("#brgr, #menu-full-size").on('mouseover', function() {
      $("#menu-full-size").addClass("is-open");  

      $('.close-nav-x').on('click', function() {
        $("#menu-full-size").removeClass("is-open"); 
      });   
  });
});
```

But i've doubt that `click` event won't trigger on svg as you wanna use `.close-nav-x` class element for triggering `click` event, better you should replace it with a button and style it using css.

## HTML

```
<div id="menu-full-size">
  <div class="close-nav">
    <button class="close-nav-x">X</button>
  </div>
  <h2>Rest of menu stuff</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: For some reason it does trigger on the svg. Is it not suppose to?

Comment: If you found that `event` triggers on svg element then you can proceed freely as i said i've doubt. If not consider using this plugin
[jQuery SVG Integration](https://github.com/kbwood/svg) if you don't want to use a button.